# Java: Hash method time complexity

Tags: java, hash, time-complexity, big-o, hashtable

I'm having trouble understand how the time complexity of a hash table is suppose to be a constant O(1). I understand with collisions how the complexity can be O(n) but if for example I have the hash method

```
public int hash(String key)
{
    int hashVal = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++)
        hashVal = 37 * hashVal + key.charAt(i);

    hashVal %= tableSize;

    if (hashVal < 0)
        hashVal += tableSize;

    return hashVal;
}
```

Assuming no collisions, shouldn't the time complexity be O(n) as the hash method itself uses a for loop to key.length() for its calculation and this method then needs to be called for the add, remove and search methods?

Comment: What is `n` here?

Comment: You are missing the definition of `n`. The _O(1)_ performance of a `HashSet` is the amortized performance of inserting one element. It doesn't care how slow the `hashCode()` method of the element is, because that is a constant (on average). E.g. if strings average a length of 42, then performance is 42, but constants are eliminated when doing Big-O, so performance is still _O(1)_, i.e. **constant** (on average).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When talking about the complexity of a hash table, n is in reference to the number of *things* you will be adding to the hash table. Yes, you could say that that (assuming no collisions) the time complexity of getting/setting an item from a hashtable is the time complexity of the hash function (which of course depends on your hash function). In the example hash function you have posted it's reasonable to assume an upper limit constant for a key's length, which means it's in practice O(1). However, if you have variable key lengths you *should* say it is O(k) where k is the length of the key.